# How to change a package's table name in Powershell or C# or VBS?

Tags: c#, powershell, vbscript, ssis

I see a command trying to change a SSIS package's table name like : `package.Variables["base_table"].Value = $tableName`

But it seems not work. Can any body tell me how to change a package table name in Powershell or C# or VBS or any others?Thanks

Comment: Did you checked your "base_table" variable is read and write variable?

Answer (score 0):

I figured that out. Before executing the command, I need to add variable,named base_table, into the SSIS package. Thanks.